# Flask app throws internal server error randomly

Tags: python, flask, amazon-ec2, psycopg2

I have setup a flask app that fetches data (using psycopg2) from my Postgres and returns it in a JSON format, when hitting the relevant URL. It works fine most of the time, but after a random number of executions it returns :

```
**Internal Server Error**

The server has encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
```

The app is hosted in an EC2 t2.micro, while the Postgres is an AWS RDS. Any ideas would be highly appreciated.

**Update**

In EC2 logs, I have seen the following Psycopg2 error

```
 psycopg2.InternalError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

Seems there's an error in the query, but shouldn't be as it runs properly most of the time.

Comment: The stack trace will help you debug what has exactly failed. Use the [flask error handler](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/errorhandling/#error-handlers) to add an error handler and log the stack trace. That should tell you what is failing.

Something like
`@app.errorhandler(Exception)
def handle_failing_request(e):
    import traceback
    traceback.print_exc()
    raise e
`

Comment: It seems the query running in psycopg2 fails after sometime, as mentioned above. The strange bit is that it generally works, but in some random time it throws 500 Internal Server Error. Yet, if I re-hit the API it returns the results properly.

Comment: It means that in during the course of a request you did not have a proper rollback made. This happens if you have `a transaction -> do_something_which_corrupts_the_transaction -> do_something_else_with_transaction` instead of properly rolling back when `do_something_which_corrupts_the_transaction` fails. You seem to have a piece of code and which raises an exception and is being caught silently.

Comment: That's what I just found too. I am implementing a transaction handler that rolls back the cursor if the transaction is corrupted. In terms of the error, do you know how/where I can view the logs and understand what's causing the exception?

Comment: I am afraid I can't do much here. If there is a 3rd party code that is silently rolling back the transaction you could look into [sqlalchemy events](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_events.html#persistent-to-transient) or you should be able to debug it step by step.